# LWJGL - Why is my triangle getting smaller when I rotate it?

Tags: java, lwjgl

In LWJGL 3.2.1 I'm drawing a triangle using vertices and viewing it with a perspective (frustum) projection. I'm trying to use the triangle to orientate myself in 3D space to figure out where I am and how to direct myself. When I rotate the triangle, it gets smaller instead of rotating around the set point.

```
glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
glLoadIdentity();
glFrustum(0, windowWidth, windowHeight, 0, 0, 100);
glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);

while (!glfwWindowShouldClose(window))
{
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);

    glPushMatrix();

    glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
    glRotatef(5f, 0f, 0f, 0f);
    glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);

    glBegin(GL_POLYGON);
    glVertex3f(-0f, -0f, 0f);
    glVertex3f(0f, 1f, 0f);
    glVertex3f(1f, 1f, 0f);
    glEnd();

    glPopMatrix();

    glfwSwapBuffers(window);
    glfwPollEvents();
}
```

Am I rotating it incorrectly or something?

Comment: When you say "gets smaller", what exactly do you mean? It's been a while since I did any opengl, but it looks like you are rotating around the X axis, which suggests the triangle would shrink vertically.

Comment: It keeps going smaller until it disappears completely. It stays on the bottom corner: https://i.imgur.com/YZWiymk.png

Comment: `glRotatef(5f, 0f, 0f, 0f);` rotates around a zero-length axis. Try changing one of those zeros to a one, depending upon the axis you want to rotate around.

Comment: Yeah, that fixed it. I just wasn't using the method correctly. Thanks.